# Storing Java Classes in Database and then Casting to them

Tags: java, validation, generics

Use-Case: Accept User Input for numerous data types and validate the user input on the back-end with Java.

Database:

```
Table 1 - Attribute Declarations

Id | Attribute Name  | Attribute Data Type
-----------------------------------------
1  | My Numeric Type | Long.class
2  | My String Type  | String.class
3  | Favorite Letter | Character.class

Table 2 - Attribute Assignments

Id | Fk | Attribute Value [Varchar2]
--------------------------
66 |  1 | 1234
67 |  2 | Some Word
68 |  3 | A
```

Problem: How do I take a value like "1234" and cast that into Long.class without knowing that it's a Long.class. I don't want to hard-code a bunch of if-else blocks because then if I need to add a new class to my DB I will need to do a code change to support it.

Pseduo:

```
public static void validate(final Class<?> dbClass, String attrValue){
    try {
        dbClass.cast(attrValue);        

    } catch(Exception e){
      LOGGER.error("ERROR: This Attribute Value is not an " 
                 + "instance of Class: {} | {}", dbClass.getSimpleName(), e);
      throw e;
    }
}
```

Current Issue: is java.lang.String cannot be cast to a Long. I know that I can do this using Long.parseLong(string), but is there a generic way I can do it for ANY class defined in my DB?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Class.forName(<Attribute Data Type>);`
and then call the string version of the constructor of that class to create a new instance of the object.  This will only work if the classes you are using have a String constructor (which Long and String does - but Character doesn't).

Do you need to store the Attribute value as a varchar in the DB?  Could you not store the serialised Java object?  Then you can just de-serialise it straight from the DB and you have the correct object already created.

Comment: Are you saying to store the attribute value as JSON so I can cast using GSON library or similar? I thought this approach might work for custom objects, but not for primitive classes like Long and String.

Comment: No, as serialised Java Objects (so they would be a blob field in the DB). Here is an example (external website) http://javapapers.com/core-java/serialize-de-serialize-java-object-from-database/

Comment: Thank you. I will check and see.